# Getting "user" in the MergeValidationListener

Tags: gerrit

I'm writing a plugin for Gerrit, that temporary locks one branch (or more) for all but one user (in order to preform a merge of two branches, for example).

I'm using Gerrit 2.11.3.

My problem is, that I can't get the current user in my implementation of the `MergeValidationListener` interface.

The code is:

```
    private final Provider<CurrentUser> user;

    ...

    user.get()
```

The exception is:

```
1) Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: No user on merge thread
  at com.google.gerrit.server.util.ThreadLocalRequestContext$1.provideCurrentUser(ThreadLocalRequestContext.java:56) (via modules: com.google.gerrit.server.config.GerritGlobalModule -> com.google.gerrit.server.util.ThreadLocalRequestContext$1)
  while locating com.google.gerrit.server.CurrentUser
  at com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginGuiceEnvironment$2.configure(PluginGuiceEnvironment.java:534) (via modules: com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginGuiceEnvironment$1 -> com.google.gerrit.server.plugins.PluginGuiceEnvironment$2)
  while locating com.google.gerrit.server.CurrentUser

1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    Caused by: com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: No user on merge thread
```

I understand it so, that the actual submit (or merge) is performed in a separated thread, that has no user context.

Is there some way to get hands on the actual user, that clicks on the "submit" button or issues the ssh-command?
Maybe there is some other Listener, that can get user information and able to prevent the submit?

As a last possibility I would consider an upgrade to a later version.